# Exclude rows that come before a specific column value in group SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, window-functions

I have table with below structure in Teradata. My analysis starts once data is uploaded i.e. status is 'UPLOADED' in STATUS column. I want to exclude rows in each group that come before STATUS becomes 'UPLOADED'. All events happen in real time i.e. Timestamp value increases for every new event.

Input table data--> table_input

```
ID  STATUS      TMP
A1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:38:44.535
A1  A           06/16/2021 16:20:40.014
A1  (B)         06/16/2021 17:15:36.488
A1  C           06/16/2021 17:15:36.846
A1  A           06/16/2021 17:15:36.883
B1  A2          06/16/2021 08:34:09.974
B1  L           06/16/2021 08:34:10.271
B1  L           06/16/2021 14:44:33.677
B1  (R)         06/16/2021 14:52:21.812
B1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 16:05:36.346
B1  AP          06/16/2021 16:05:36.499
B1  (R)         06/16/2021 16:05:36.718
C1  C           06/16/2021 16:05:36.764
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:49:43.796
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:49:43.841
C1  L           06/16/2021 14:50:39.667
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 14:52:50.149
C1  (R)         06/16/2021 16:05:43.998
```

Expected OUTPUT : Data before the STATUS is 'UPLOADED' is excluded from results.

```
ID  STATUS      TMP
A1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:38:44.535
A1  A           06/16/2021 16:20:40.014
A1  (B)         06/16/2021 17:15:36.488
A1  C           06/16/2021 17:15:36.846
A1  A           06/16/2021 17:15:36.883
B1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 16:05:36.346
B1  AP          06/16/2021 16:05:36.499
B1  (R)         06/16/2021 16:05:36.718
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:49:43.796
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 08:49:43.841
C1  L           06/16/2021 14:50:39.667
C1  UPLOADED    06/16/2021 14:52:50.149
C1  (R)         06/16/2021 16:05:43.998
```

I am using Teradata SQL but SQL Server SQL should also work.
I am trying with window functions but did not get any success yet.
We can also use TMP column with TimeStamp and code a logic e.g. Exclude all rows with TimeStamp value less than TimeStamp of First occurrence of 'UPLOADED'.

Comment: @DaleK I will remember this going forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `qualify` clause in Teradata:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify tmp >= min(case when status = 'UPLOADED' then tmp end) over (partition by id);
```

And, although you can use window functions for this, it can also be written with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.tmp > (select min(t2.tmp)
               from t t2
               where t2.id = t.id and t2.status = 'UPLOADED'
              );
```